# html and php contact form trouble

Tags: php, html

Can somebody please tell me what is wrong with my code. I cant figure out what the error is.

contact form

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
                <p>Name</p> <input type="text" name="name">
                <p>Email</p> <input type="text" name="email">
                <p>Phone</p> <input type="text" name="telephone">

                <p>Request Phone Call:</p>
                Yes:<input type="checkbox" value="Yes" name="call">
                No:<input type="checkbox" value="No" name="call"><br />

                <p>Priority</p>
                <select name="priority" size="1">
                    <option value="Low">Low</option>
                    <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
                    <option value="High">High</option>
                    <option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>
                </select>
                <br />

                <p>Type</p>
                <select name="type" size="1">
                    <option value="update">Website Update</option>
                    <option value="change">Information Change</option>
                    <option value="addition">Information Addition</option>
                    <option value="new">General Enquiries</option>
                </select>
                <br />

                <p>Message</p><textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea><br />
                <input type="submit" value="Send" class="button"/><input type="reset" value="Clear" class="button"/>
            </form>
```

mail.php

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['email'])) { 

$email_to = "myemail@sky.com"; 
$email_subject = "Tip Top Music"; 

function died($error) { 

    // Error codes
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. "; 
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />"; 
    echo $error."<br /><br />";  
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />"; 
    die(); 

} 

// Required fields
if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||  
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||   
    !isset($_POST['message'])) { 

    died('Required Fields are not complete');        
} 

$name = $_POST['name']; // required 
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required 
$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required 
if(!isset($_POST['call'])) {
 $call = "No"; // if checkbox was left unchecked. Default is No
}
else {
    $call = ($_POST['call'])
}
$priority = $_POST['priority'];  // Will already have default value
$type = $_POST['type'];  // Will already have default value
$message = $_POST['message']; // required 
$error_message = ""; 

$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/'; 

if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) { 
  $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />'; 
} 

$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/"; 

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) { 
    $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />'; 
}

if(strlen($message) < 2) { 
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />'; 
} 

if(strlen($error_message) > 0) { 
    died($error_message); 
} 

$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n"; 

function clean_string($string) { 
    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href"); 
    return str_replace($bad,"",$string); 
} 

$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n"; 
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n"; 
$email_message .= "Request Callback: ".($call)."\n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n"; 
$email_message .= "Priority: ".($priority)."\n";
$email_message .= "Type: ".($type)."\n";
$email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n"; 

// create email headers 
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n". 
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" . 
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);   

?> 

<!-- Message success --> 

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon. 

<?php 


} 

?>
```

I get undefined index call pointing to $call = "No"; line. HOWEVER the script should not even run at all because I posted a blank form?? When I echo the input fields they are blank but they if put IF statements in to check if they are set (isset) it goes into the statement as if they have been set? Should I be using something other than isset to check for empty inputs? This usually works so im confused as to why its not now?

Comment: @vinodadhikary what do you mean? died is the name of a function in there

Comment: sorry didn't notice that!

Comment: About the form : the 'request phone call' part is a Yes/No question. Use either one checkbox, or two radio buttons. Don't use two checkboxes.

Comment: @Theox thanks I changed this to a radio button and made the default no. Changed the code so no longer need the If statement however my code still see the inputs as being set when I submit a blank form??

Answer (score 3):

Your code is working fine after adding missing semicolon to $_POST['call'];

correct one should be $call = ($_POST['call']);

when submitting empty form it gives error messages. so i think validation is working fine.

Comment: If submitting a fully empty form the script shouldnt even run. It first checks to see if the email field has been set - If not it shouldnt even run the next line. Instead it bypasses the code that checks for empty inputs of name, email and message as it sees these as being set when they wernt. Yes it gives errors to say the name, email and message are not valid but it shouldnt have got that far in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Missing semicolon on `$_POST['call']`

```
if(!isset($_POST['call'])) {
 $call = "No"; // if checkbox was left unchecked. Default is No
}
else {
    $call = $_POST['call']; // Missing semicolon here
}
```

Comment: Thats fixed my compile error however still having the problem that it thinks the inputs have been set? Its still running the code even though I submitted an empty form?

Comment: died is just a function that adds extra comments then kills the script. Even if I do change that line to die it never runs because it never enters into that if statement. My code is seeing the variable (name, email and message) as being set even though I havent and so carries on with the code givng the error messages that the name, email and message is not valid.

Comment: I have had to change my !isset's to !=null this is the only way I can get it to work as it should

Comment: Okay I was thought isset by default do if null is passed :)